# Convert ASCII File to netCDF using Python (selective columns from ASCII file)

Tags: python, numpy, ascii, netcdf

Firstly I am new to this forum so please excuse as to any mistake I am doing in posting here. I would be glad if you could point me my mistakes out and I will make sure I don't repeat them when I post any thing else.

Task: Converting ASCII Data Files (UCAC 4 Star Catalog) to netCDF Format using Python. Only output some fixed number of columns from ASCII file to netCDF file.

Problem:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Work 1\FINAL\New Try\txt2nc.py", line 51, in 
    vic_runoff[ra,spd,:,:] = output;
    File "netCDF4.pyx", line 2821, in netCDF4.Variable.**setitem**
    (netCDF4.c:35204)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\netCDF4_utils.py", line 187, in
    _StartCountStride
    ee = range(start,stop,step)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 4102, in
    **int**
    raise MaskError('Cannot convert masked element to a Python int.') 
    MaskError: Cannot convert masked element to a Python int.**

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated!

```
    from __future__ import division
    from netCDF4 import Dataset
    import numpy as np
    import os

    PATH = 'D:\\Internship Work 1\\Alok Data\\ASCII'
    LL = np.loadtxt('%s\\4uc001.txt' %PATH, delimiter='|', usecols = 
     (0,1,2,3), skiprows=0);
    LL = LL[:,:]

    # NC file setup
    root_grp = Dataset('%s\\4uc001.nc' %PATH, 'w', format='NETCDF4')
    root_grp.description = 'Star Catalog UCAC Data'

    # dimensions
    ra = root_grp.createDimension('ra', 32)
    spd = root_grp.createDimension('spd', 80)
    magm = root_grp.createDimension('magm', 96)
    maga = root_grp.createDimension('maga', 120)


    # variables
    ra = root_grp.createVariable('ra', np.byte, ('ra',))
    spd = root_grp.createVariable('spd', np.byte, ('spd',))
    magm = root_grp.createVariable('magm', np.byte, ('magm'),)
    maga = root_grp.createVariable('maga', np.byte, ('maga'),)
    vic_runoff = root_grp.createVariable('vic_runoff', np.byte, ('ra',
     'spd', 'magm', 'maga',))

    ra.units = 'mas'
    spd.units = 'mas'
    magm.units = 'millimag'
    maga.units = 'millimag'

    for ra in enumerate(ra):
      tempstore = np.zeros((206,4),int)


    output_filename = 'D:\\Internship Work 1\\Alok Data\\ASCII\\4uc001.txt'

    output = np.loadtxt(output_filename,delimiter='|',usecols = (0,1,2,3))

    tempstore[:,:] = output # ensembles x months
    vic_runoff[ra,spd,:,:] = tempstore[:,:] # write all ensembles to netcdf

    print('work done')
```

Answer (score 2):

A few comments that will hopefully help you:

In `vic_runoff[ra,spd,:,:]`, `spd` is a netCDF4 variable.  It can not be used as an indexer. Try `vic_runoff[ra,0,:,:] = tempstore[:,:]` to see if that fixes your problem.

Also, you should consider using `pandas.read_csv` or `read_table` to read your ASCII files. There's a SO post around here documenting the performance improvement over `numpy.loadtxt`

Lastly, if you went the pandas route, you may consider using `xarray` for the writing to netCDF.  `xarray` easily allows you to convert from pandas to a `xarray.Dataset` then you're whole netCDF file is written with a quick `Dataset.to_netcdf()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will surely try it out let you know

Comment: Thank You very much! I tried using `pandas` and `xarray` and its working now, I will post the solution here soon for others!